# Navier stokes equation - two dimensional simplified

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

The general Navier Stokes Equation is
$\dfrac{D\vec{v}}{D t}= \dfrac{d\vec{v}}{d t}+ \vec{v} .\nabla \vec{v} = \vec{g} -  \dfrac{1}{\rho} \nabla p + \nu \nabla^2 \vec{v}$

The above equation can be reduced by the following assumptions

- Two dimensional flow
- Steady state
- u >> v
- $\mid \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mid  \gg \mid\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mid$
- p = $\neq f(y)$
- $\nu =$ constant

The above equation reduces to 
In the x- direction

$u\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\dfrac{1}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \nu\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$

Then how can the above equation be reduced to the form
$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial uv}{\partial y} = -\dfrac{1}{\rho}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \nu\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}\right)$

The above equation was seen by me in A heat transfer textbook by John H Linehard around page 280, while deriving the Navier Stokes Equation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted and answered on [math.se]

Comment: x-posted on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919281/289977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final form of the equation, the first terms is incorrect.  It should read $\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x}$.  The correct form of the final equation is obtained by first taking the continuity equation and multiplying it by u to obtain:
$$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$$You then add this to your next-to-last equation.